# Why my flutter http network calls are slow?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, http, dart

I am developing a flutter application with network activities. To get data, I am connecting to a `REST API`, this API is fast as it should.

For more information, this API is using `AWS API Gateway` and `AWS Lambda` along with other AWS technologies.

Below is my code, connecting to network.

```
class RoleService with ChangeNotifier {
  NavLinks _navLinks = NavLinks();
  late List<Role> _roles;



  /// Get all Roles
  Future<void> getAllRoles(String authToken) async {
    try {
      var data = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("https://api2.example.com/userrel/roles/getall"),
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $authToken"},
      );
      var jsonData =
          convert.json.decode(data.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      _roles = jsonData.map<Role>((json) => new Role.fromJson(json)).toList();
      print(_roles);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the `postman` performance of the above `API` call below. For flutter testing, i am using **Huawei p30 Lite** android phone.

[image]

Then, when I execute the same `API` call in flutter, this is what I get.

[image]

Observing the outputs from `postman` I can see it has cached the DNS Lookup, TCP Handshake and SSL Handshake. postman does this after calling the API base URI for the first time. Then from the 2nd time onwards, the DNS Lookup etc are cached saving lot of time in future API calls to the same base URI.

But in flutter the "Connection established" time is high, even though the time to retrieve data is only few milliseconds.

How can I avoid the connection delays and get the maximum performance? If caching the SSL, DNS Lookup etc is the solution, how can I do that in flutter?

Comment: Did you tried testing on profile mode?

Comment: Could you try speedtest.net on your device? I wouldn't have expected you to optimize Flutter's network requests by doing any caching like this.

Comment: @7mada i managed to find the solution by my own. i have posted the answer.

Comment: @BenButterworth: i managed to find the solution by my own. i have posted the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems this question is there for many people. So, let me answer my own question.

**Can flutter remember the network connection? Yes it can.**

Flutter only require one network call to the same API to remember the connection. From the second call onward to the same API, it will use its "cached" memory giving you a big performance boost.

So first remember, this only works if you are calling the same API multiple times. If you are calling different APIs, this will not work. However in many apps, you have an API that built by the API team and you will be calling the same throughput the app.

The solution is to use flutter [http.Client](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client-class.html). Then share the same `http.Client` across the calls you make to the same API. You will see only first call takes time for "connection", rest of the calls do not take that time.

An example is available in flutter [http pub page](https://pub.dev/packages/http). It says ,

> If you're making multiple requests to the same server, you can keep
> open a persistent connection by using a Client rather than making
> one-off requests. If you do this, make sure to close the client when
> you're done:

Check below example. It is only for your reference, not the best way of using this.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:network_test/role_service.dart';
import 'package:network_test/user_role_service.dart';
import 'package:network_test/user_service.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var startTime = "";
  var endTime = "";

  void _network() async {
    var client = http.Client();

    RoleService _roleService = RoleService();
    UserService _userService = UserService();
    UserRoleService _userRoleService = UserRoleService();

    String authToken = "****";

    String uid = "555555";
    try {
      await _roleService.getAllRoles(authToken, client);
      //await _roleService.getAllRoles(authToken, client);
      await _userService.getUserByUID(authToken, uid, client);
      await _userService.getUserByID(authToken, 27, client);
      await _userRoleService.getUserRoleByUser(authToken, 27, client);
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              "Start Time: " + startTime,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Text(
              "End Time: " + endTime,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _network,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**role_service.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:network_test/role.dart';
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'dart:io';

class RoleService with ChangeNotifier {
  late List<Role> _roles;
  String link2 = "https://api2.somewhere.com/userrel";

  /// Return roles
  List<Role> returnRoles() {
    return _roles;
  }

  /// Get all Roles
  Future<void> getAllRoles(String authToken, Client client) async {
    try {
      var data = await client.get(Uri.parse(link2 + "/role/getall"),
          headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $authToken"});

     
      var jsonData =
          convert.json.decode(data.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      _roles = jsonData.map<Role>((json) => Role.fromJson(json)).toList();
      print(_roles[0].roleName);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

now I told you that above is not the best practice.  Why? Because you will be creating and destroying the `http.Client` in many different places. Let's pay attention to a better practice.

In almost every app, we use State Management. I am a fan of `Provider`, it could be anything of your choice. i figured out the best way is to let the state management to remember the creation of `http.Client`. Since I am using `Provider`, I created the following class.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ConnectionService with ChangeNotifier {
  http.Client _client = http.Client();

  http.Client returnConnection() {
    return _client;
  }
}
```

And this is my main class

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ConnectionService()),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

Now when the app opens, I call the `ConnectionService` class to make the connection and do my API calls such as checking user authentication, user access etc. And only the first call is taking its time to build the connection, other calls do not.

Comment: can you please upload riverpod implementation

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add to PeakGen's answer. I was using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for making API requests from my Flutter App. I noticed that I had a connection wait time of >200ms for all of my APIs and this was slowing down my overall API performance. See DevTool screenshot below.

[image: Lot of time before connection was established]

Upon digging I found that Dio uses socket connection to send/receive data. I also found that it overrides the [idealTimeout](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.4/dart-io/HttpClient/idleTimeout.html) parameter and [sets its value to 3s](https://github.com/cfug/dio/blob/420400403b8dba09faa6c4ef6e77ee94c3c10616/dio/lib/src/adapters/io_adapter.dart#L198). As a consequence, whenever there's a delay of more than 3s between API calls, Dio has to open a new socket connection because the previous one has closed. This contributes to connection wait time and slow APIs overall.

I changed the `idealTimeout` value to 15s and API performance improved drastically after it.

[image: Zero connection wait time after optimization]

There's a separate SO thread where I've described how I found the issue and explained things with a bit more detail - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75750623/10505839)