# http requests are very slow in flutter

Tags: flutter, http

I am using the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package to call my API, but every request takes 8+ seconds to complete.

I have tried calling the same route via **browser** and **postman** and I get the response in less than a second. Also, I can assure that there is no issue with my internet connection.

```
class ApiRest {
  Future<List<Product>> getProducts() async {
    final apiResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse('some route'));
    final resBody = jsonDecode(apiResponse.body);
    return resBody['products']
        .map<Product>((product) => Product.fromJson(product))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

Additionally, I tried applying the approach recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69268170/10901093), using the HTTP `Client()`, which didn't make a difference either.

Is there anything I am doing wrong or inefficient?

Lastly, the latest version of the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package for `Flutter` is currently **0.13.4**. Do you think that the issue might be with this package? Or it might not be stable enough?

Comment: can you share the route so that i can test?

Comment: @towhid Unfortunately, I can not share the route.

Comment: did you try using any other public route?

Comment: I am communicating with my server via 20+ routes and all of them are slow with flutter. There might be some issues with my server. However the same routes are much faster in **browser** and **postman**.

Comment: Are you sure that `http.get(Uri.parse('some route'));` is the bottle neck? Try to see how much time the actual request takes. My guess is that your JSON parsing is the actual bottle neck.

Comment: @JosipDomazet JSON parsing takes less than 50 milliseconds, While HTTP requests take more than 7 seconds.

Comment: @EhsanAskari are you by any chance testing on IOS?

Comment: @JosipDomazet I am on Android.

Comment: @Ehsan That is weird. There is an open issue that http is slow on IOS but that does not apply here. Could it be that your phone just has a really bad connection? Try opening one route in the browser of the phone or try your app on an emulator.

Comment: @EhsanAskari  Did u find any solution for this issue???pls reply..